# rails 4, turbolinks 3, partial replacement not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I'm trying rails/turbolinks 3, and want to make partial replacement work, but no luck with that. Here is code:

gemfile
`gem 'turbolinks', github: 'rails/turbolinks'` (shows using 3.0.0 so problem not in that, turbolinks included in app..n.js).

router:

```
  root 'home#index'

  get '/partial1' => 'home#partial1', as: 'partial1'

  get '/partial2' => 'home#partial2', as: 'partial2'
```

controller

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end

  def partial1
    render change: 'partial1'
  end

  def partial2
    render change: 'partial2'
  end
end
```

layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Turbo</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  this is home
  <%= link_to("partial asd1", partial1_path) %>
  <%= link_to "partial 2", partial2_path%>
</div>


<div id="partial1" data-turbolinks-temporary>
  <p>her</p>
</div>

<div id="partial2">
  <p>here is partial</p>
</div>
<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't replace those partials, it works just as regular. I also tried to put `turbolinks: true` and it renders `Turbolinks.replace('some html', {change: ['partial1']})`, but also nothing happens. I also tried e.preventDefault and `Turbolinks.visit('/partial1', {change: 'partial1'})`, and it also not working as well as calling `Turbolinks.replace('some html', {change: 'partial1'})`. Turbolinks js loads in browser all right. And in dev it shows calling `Turbolinks.visit`. Tried on different machines.

If anyone made it work please tell me how you did it.

Comment: What do you mean by partial replacement?

Comment: that's a new beta feature in turbolinks which will be a part of rails 5 and will make it easy to make SPA (sort of) without hellish js frameworks. You can read more on https://github.com/rails/turbolinks.

Comment: Hey did you solve it? I am having the same issue.

Comment: As far as I understood, this Turbolinks feature is not made for navigation (changing url for new request and replacing some partial), but rather for updating current "view". Try youtube/spfjs, it'll do what you want, and is really easy to use.

Comment: I think this is a great question!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. What's your advice? Should I just drop it? Or there is actually a solution?

Comment: Well, I just use Rails for and API now and client-side as singlepage React with React router. Moreover I do React in Ruby via Opal (worth checking out). I've made a wrapper and client side model layer for it so no single line of JS will be required Ruby only both on server and client - https://github.com/classyPimp/turboPimp (the docs are a bit outdated but you will get the point).